# Give an example of a function that satisfies strict inequality in Fatou's lemma and ....

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Find a sequence of functions $f_n\ge 0 $ that is continuous on the interval $[0,1]$ satisfies $\int f_n dm \leq 1$ and strict inequality occur in Fatou's lemma.

I could find one that satisfies the strict inequality but discontinuous. 
example characteristics function $f_n(x)=\large{X}_{[n,n+1]}(x)$.
but I need  one that is continuous as well and satisfies all the above.
any assisstance is appreciated.

Comment: Could you take $X_{[n,n+1]}(x)$ and "round out" the edges so that the integral stays less than 1 but it becomes continuous?

Comment: By 'round out' the edges you mean make the interval an open one? $(n,n+1)$ .

Comment: No I more mean connect the discontinuous points at the edges of the interval in a continuous way such that the integral becomes strictly less than 1. I can post an image if you'd like.

Comment: Kindly post the image for me.

Comment: Note that those characteristic functions are not defined on $[0,1].$

Answer (score 1):

Try the sequence $f_n(x) = n^2x^n(1-x).$

Comment: I have 'tested' it against all the conditions and I think it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make $X_[n,n+1]$ continuous by shrinking the interval where your function is exactly one, and connecting the points in a small epsilon neighborhood of $n$ and $n+1$, like so
[image]

In this way, the integral is $<1$, but the function becomes continuous.

The "rounding out" that I was referring to was to make the function differentiable, which is not needed in your question. I apologize for misreading, and for my horrible drawing :)